# Cómo cumplir PEP8 con if anidados

Tags: python

Tengo un código como el siguiente:

```
if condición:
    if condición:
        if confición:
        else:
    else:
else:
```

Son tantos if anidados que sobrepasan con creces los 79 caracteres que recomienda PEP 8 y como quiero hacer que mi código cumpla con la regla de estilo.

¿Cómo puedo anidar muchos if y no sobrepasar los 79 caracteres?

Con string es fácil, utilizo un \ y listo, lo mismo con paréntesis...

Comment: Examina los condicionales; muchos, con seguridad, pueden ser agrupados en métodos con pocos parámetros de entrada y pasa por referencia los parámetros (exteriores) que puedan ser afectados dentro de los métodos.

Comment: Completamente de acuerdo con quevedo, si llegas a tal número de anidamiento, más que preocuparte por superar los 79 caracteres debes preocuparte por la  legibilidad de ese código. Generalmente cuando se llegan a estos casos el código se puede refactorizar y eliminar anidamiento vía métodos/funciones, usando alguna variable auxiliar, etc dependiendo del caso.

Comment: Si pones el código te podriamos ayudar :)

Comment: Me habéis dado una buena idea, utilizaré un while a ver si así... si veo que no lo consigo os daré más detalles del ccódigo que estoy haciendo para mi TFG, pero está relacionado con los permisos del usuario, algo tipo: 
if usuario.editar = true: 
    print(este usuario puede editar)
    if usuario.eliminar:
        print(este usuario puede editar y eliminar)

Comment: y porque no usas el comando `case`

Comment: @ fwBasic ¿Por ejemplo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He encontrado la solución:

Supoiendo que tengo que comprobar:

```
código = comando_que_devuelve_un_código_de_estado
if codigo != 0:
    código = otro_comando_que_devuelve_un_código_de_estado1
    if código != 0:
        código = otro_comando_que_devuelve_un_código_de_estado2
        .
        .
        .
    else:
        return "ERROR"
else:
    return "ERROR"
```

lo he cambiado a:

```
comandos = [comando_que_devuelve_un_codigo_de_estado,
            otro_comando_que_devuelve_un_código_de_estado1,
            otro_comando_que_devuelve_un_código_de_estado2,
                             .
                             .
                             .                             ]
for comando in comandos:
    if comando == 0:
        return "ERROR"
```

¿Qué os parece esta solución?